# SQL ORDER BY a calculation of two columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Hey there I want to order my sql query by a calculation of two columns in a table. This calculation is `(col1/col2)*100` how would I go about ordering by this?

Like ORDER BY `(col1/col2)*100` DESC?

I can't find anything online for this so all help would be appreciated.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: what purpose does `*100` serve?  `ORDER BY col1/col2` will yield the same result as it is 100% correlated

Comment: It should work just like that (event better without the `*100`) - provided that `col2` is never `0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT col1, col2, (col1/col2)*100 as total
  FROM your table
ORDER BY 3 DESC
/
```